# Wait for ajax to finish in javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Basically I need a way to wait for the ajax call in the `uniqueID()` function to finish before it returns a value to the while call in the `createColumns()` function. Currently everything works fine however in HTML the id is undefined and about half a second after the functions are complete the id's that should be in the html are alerted.

The difference between my question and the one that was marked duplicate is that my call is in a while loop. Which means a callback function in success is not possible.

Please let me know if this doesn't make much sense. Thanks!

```js
var uniqueid = ""; 
function uniqueID() {
  uniqueid = "";
  $.ajax({
    url: '....',
    type: 'post',
    data: { "uniqueidfunc": "1"},
    success: function(response) { 
      uniqueid = response; 
      alert(uniqueid);
      return uniqueid;
    }
  });
}

var i = "";
var columns = "";
function createColumns(x) {
  i = 0;
  columns = "";
  while (i < x) {
    columns += '<div class="column col-'+x+'" id="'+uniqueID()+'"></div>';
  i++;
  };
  return columns; 
}

$(document).delegate('.tcolumn', 'click', function(){
 colummnum = $(this).attr("id");
 colummnum = colummnum.replace("tcolumn-", "");
 $(this).parent().next().html(createColumns(colummnum));
});
```

Comment: What is the purpose of using a `while` loop ? What is expected result of `uniqueID()` ?

Comment: Am I being blind? Where do you call createColumns() in the first place?

Comment: @guest271314 The while loop creates the number of divs as per the number of columns clicked.

Comment: @amflare I've edited the function call in thanks.

Comment: @Xirlas You should be able to achieve requirement using single `.then()` following `$.ajax()` call

Comment: @guest271314 Like this: $.ajax().then({ ? That didn't work for me.

Comment: @Xirlas The `while` loop does not appear necessary. You can update `html` within `success` function or `$.ajax().then(function(response) { colummnum = $(event.target).attr("id");
 colummnum = colummnum.replace("tcolumn-", "");
 $(this).parent().next().html("<div class=column col-"+colummnum+" id="+response+"></div>");})`